# Program has error lines which are remarked by ???? .I could not understand where the problem is

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

Scanner myinput=new Scanner(System.in) ;  //Arrary length comes from user!
System.out.println("Enter a number: ") ;  
int sayi=myinput.nextInt() ;

int [] Array = new int [sayi] ;  

for(int i=0; i<SayiDizisi.length ; i++){ //Fill the array!(Comes from user)
    System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ") ;
    SayiDizisi[i]=myinput.nextInt() ;}
}

Max(int [] SayiDizisi) ; // ???????????????????????????????????
}

public static int Max(int [] Array1) {    
    int max=SayiDizisi1[0] ;
    for(int i=0; i<SayiDizisi1.length ; i++) {
      if(SayiDizisi1[i]>max)
        max=SayiDizisi1[i] ;  
}


  return SayiDizisi ;   //?????????????????????


  }
}
```

Comment: Alper, please try not to edit the question in ways that invalidate the answers. It makes SO a much less useful site when questions and answers don't match :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, you should not have the `int []` type in the method call. Change:

```
Max (int[] SayiDizisi);
```

to:

```
Max (SayiDizisi);
```

Secondly, your `Max` function is expected to return an integer but it's returning an array of integers. Change its return statement from:

```
return SayiDizisi;
```

to:

```
return max;
```

Thirdly, I can't see where `SayiDizisi` is defined anywhere. You appear to be creating an array to be populated but you've called it `Array`. Change:

```
int[] Array = new int[sayi];
```

to:

```
int[] SayiDizisi = new int[sayi];
```

Finally, your braces are not balanced. See the line `SayiDizisi[i]=myinput.nextInt() ;}` - it has a superfluous brace at the end which causes the compiler to misunderstand your intent.

---

Here's a fully functioning one with those fixes made, and some comments added for your education:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scratch {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        // Get the count and allocate array.

        Scanner myinput = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter a number: ");
        int sayi = myinput.nextInt();

        int[] SayiDizisi = new int[sayi];

        // Get the values into the array.

        for (int i = 0; i < SayiDizisi.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println ("Enter the numbers: ");
            SayiDizisi[i] = myinput.nextInt();
        }

        // Output the maximum.

        int x = Max (SayiDizisi);
        System.out.println ("Maximum is: " + x);
    }

    public static int Max(int[] Array1) {
        // Assume first is largest.

        int max = Array1[0] ;

        // Check all others, finding larger.

        for (int i = 0; i < Array1.length ; i++) {
            if (Array1[i] > max)
                max = Array1[i];
        }

        // Return the largest found.

        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: The worst problem is he's adding code to bad code. To the OP, if you're not using an IDE then compile often, fix any and all errors encountered, and don't add any new code until the current code compiles without errors.